# How do i create app service on particular virtual machine in Azure?

Tags: azure

I am creating app service on Azure. The app service is taking it's own ip address. How to create app service on a particular virtual machine in Azure.

Answer (score 1):

With public app service environments you cannot. (part of the point of using App Service is so you don't need to worry about the VMs)

If you really need that, then there is [App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-intro). It allows you to create your own environment in a virtual network.

It is a premium offering (quite expensive), but it allows you to control the public IP addresses etc.